# How to fix my webpack error during project build?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When I try to build my React project, Webpack gives me this error :

> The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script

**I read what it could be connected with, and I realized that in my project there are many imports of the following type:**

```
import { onAuthStateChanged, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-auth.js";
```

That is, the import comes from an external source, not locally. As far as I understand the problem is this.

**I have no way to change such imports to be suitable for the assembly. How it is possible to bypass this problem?**

Git repo : [link](https://github.com/YevheniiBrodovskyii/Hotel-Review-App)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your package.json file

> "type": "module"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem on a Vanilla JS project that was importing Firebase. Adding the following to **webpack.config.js** worked for me:

```
experiments: {
  outputModule: true
}
```

See docs here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externalstypemodule